# Ngnix - make app.php executable

Tags: symfony

I want that app.php is executable, just like index.php. How can I set this up?

It's for symfony, because symfony has no index.php.

Answer (score 0):

it'is already executable! I think you mean to make apache to look for app.php instead of index.php, to do that you should config your .htaccess file and add somethink like that :

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for a local virtual host with php5-fpm

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name your.site.lan;

    root /var/www/your.site.lan/web;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/site.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/site.access.log;

    # strip app.php/ prefix if it is present
    rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    location / {
        index app.php;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server from upstream phpfcgi
    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|index|app_test|config|info|apc)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass phpfcgi;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

where phpfcgi is alias configured at nginx.conf at http section

```
upstream phpfcgi {
        server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```